# Create dymanic tab and load the data from the url is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created the dynamic tab but not able to load the data from the url.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {


    var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
        region:'center',
        activeTab:0,
        margins: '5 5 5 0',

        resizeTabs:true, 
        minTabWidth: 115,
        items:[{ 
            title: 'Dashboard',
            contentEl: 'simple-form',
            closable:true
        }]

    });

    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border', 
        defaults: {
            collapsible: false,
            split: true
        },
        items: [{    
            title:'PSL Admin',
            region: 'north',
            contentEl: 'north', 
            margins: '5 5 5 5',
            split:false 
        },{
            title:'Navigation',
            collapsible: true, 
            region:'west',
            contentEl: 'west', 
            margins: '5 0 5 5',
            cmargins: '5 5 5 5',
            width: 175,
            minSize: 100,
            maxSize: 250 
        },

        tabs 
        ]

    });

    function addTab(){
       tabs.add({
        title: 'Bar',
        closable: true,
        plain: true,
        loader: {
            autoLoad:true,
            url :'test.html'
        }

        });

    }

    Ext.get('add').on('click', function(){
        addTab();
    });

});
```

Whenever I am clicking the button just calling the above function, I can see the tab, but content is not loaded.

Can anyone help where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming you are using the latest version of ExtJS 4.1

Here is a working snipped:

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        title: 'Foo'
    }]
});

tabs.add({
    title: 'Bar',
    closable: true,
    plain: true,
    loader: {
        autoLoad:true,
        url :'http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/ComponentLoader.html#Ext-ComponentLoader'
    }

});
```

Note that there is **no need** for calling `show()` on a tab. This is for Windows or other floating components

I don't see any reason why your code shouldn't work. You can try this snipped by yourself by placing it in one of the [example windows of the ExtJS API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)

***Update***

I removed some parts and again tested this code successful. Just a guess; you supply a invalid url. Try a absolute path as url just for testing purpose and see if it works this. way.

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    region:'center',
    activeTab:0,
    margins: '5 5 5 0',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    resizeTabs:true, 
    minTabWidth: 115,
    items:[{ 
        title: 'Dashboard',
        //contentEl: 'simple-form',
        closable:true
    }]

});

var addTab = function(){
   tabs.add({
    title: 'Bar',
    closable: true,
    plain: true,
    loader: {
        autoLoad:true,
        url :'http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/ComponentLoader.html#Ext-ComponentLoade'
    }

    });

}

addTab();
```

Comment: @user1584844 As I wrote, this is a working example. You will have to provide more code for further help.

Comment: Still i am not getting can you look at my source

Comment: @user1584844 I guess your problem is the `url` format. Try a absolute url and see if it works.

Comment: i am not getting.. if i am giving the html content directly it works otherwise not working.

Comment: @user1584844 I see no reason why this should not work. And I told you to insert a absolute url like in my example, not to test it in the browser or add the content of the file.

Comment: for example just i am giving                                                                  url :'test.html

Comment: @user1584844 You can register yourself to the `beforeload` `exception` `load` event to see which one get called for more details. Print the to the console or attach yourself directly with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any javascripts code in that HTML file you are refering in url, then you must use the scripts: true configuration in loader . am posting this answer by assuming that you are using extjs4.1 and above version.

our code must look like this,

```
    var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    region:'center',
    activeTab:0,
    margins: '5 5 5 0',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    resizeTabs:true, 
    minTabWidth: 115,
    items:[{ 
      title: 'Dashboard',
     //contentEl: 'simple-form',
     closable:true
    }]

   });

   var addTab = function(){
   tabs.add({
    title: 'Bar',
   closable: true,
   plain: true,
   loader: {
    autoLoad:true,
      url :'http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/ComponentLoader.html#Ext-   ComponentLoade',
      scripts: true,
    }

   });

  }

   addTab();
```